# Showing subpages based on a session in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am begginer in Laravel. I am use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I need to do something so that a specific route can be viewed by a user with a php adult = 1 session.

I have route:

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/sample1', 'FrontendController@sample1')->name('sample1');
```

The SAMPLE1 view is for users with php adult = 1 session.
If the user does not have such a session - it must be automatically redirected to @ index

How can you do this?

Comment: You can use middleware like auth. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: can you show me sample with session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom middleware, take a look at the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Instead of using session, you can maintain a user is adult or not on the `users` table, which means you can access this info via authenticated user (which is available throughout the whole app).

For e.g. in your app, use `php artisan make:auth` and this will scaffold out everything you need to for a register/login system. Before you run the migration, add a new field to the `create_users_table` migration, e.g. `$table->boolean('adult')->default(false);`

Then once the migration is ran, you can create a new middleware using: `php artisan make:middleware CheckAdult` with something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckAdult
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!auth()->check() || !auth()->user()->adult) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The above middleware will redirect anyone who is not logged in or have `adult = 0` back to index page, otherwise continue with their request.

Then register the middleware and use it in the routes; as per the documentation.

Comment: you think something like this: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!isset($request->session()->put('fullAge', '1'))) {
            return redirect('index');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }?

Comment: i am sorry i dont understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use auth and middleware to achieve this. the simple logic would be something like this: `$id = Auth::user()->adult;` in your controller to check for users. ofcorse adult is a field in your table.

```
//on top of your controller place this
    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

//control logic to check user
    if($adult==1){
          //perform unique task
    }else{
       return redirect('/')->with('message','You are not permitted')
    }
```